# How to export Victory Chart to png?

Tags: reactjs, d3.js, screenshot, victory-charts

This might be a very particular use case but I have a React app which uses Victory Charts. I need to get a screenshot of the chart and export it as a png.
I have done some research and here are some ideas that I have so far:

1. Export it using some functionality within victory.js itself. The closest I could get is: https://github.com/FormidableLabs/victory/issues/781#event-1281057513 But this approach doesn't work. I've tested it. It gives me a reference to the Chart's container though which might be useful.
2. Use some 'screenshot' library I tried saveSvgAsPng and made this: https://codesandbox.io/s/victory-chart-to-png-k9zo8 But this doesn't work too and I can't figure out why not.
3. Use some sort of implementation using D3.js upon which victory charts is built. But I have no idea how to do that too.

If you guys have any idea about how this sort of thing can be done, please let me know.

Comment: Hey @kronaemmanuel any update on the solution?

Answer (score 1):

In order to saveSvgAsPng to work, you have to pass an `<SVG>` element to it.
After reviewing your code at https://codesandbox.io/s/victory-chart-to-png-k9zo8, you evidently passed a `Container` element to it.
There `this.state.ref` refers to the Container element but not the `<SVG>` element. Change `this.state.ref` to `this.state.ref.firstChild` which refers to the `<SVG>` element in the container. And the library works like a charm in downloading the SVG as PNG.